# Automating Command In Browser (IE clicking a button)

Tags: javascript, browser, automation

How would I go about writing code that would automatically do a command on my browser (for example, click the 'ask question' button on this webpage ***x*** times), without using something like an auto-clicker?

I am studying computer science at University, so I know how to code in various languages, but I have no idea where to start looking for the answer to this question, when I hardly know what questions I need to be asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your want to search for automated testing tools, since that's where this type of feature is frequently used. A popular one is [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).